# What does `extern` do when getting a global variable inside a block? (with a different variable defined with the same name)

Tags: c, global, local, extern

I recently learned global and local variables in C, and I found this example on the internet(with no clear explanation)

```
#include<stdio.h>

int x = 50;

int main(){
    int x = 10;
    {
      extern int x;
      printf("global: %d\n", x);
    }
    printf("local: %d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

I did understand that you can make local and global variables in the same program with the same name(and the local var will take preference inside that function or block), and so the result for `printf("local: %d\n", x);`would be `local: 10`. But I could not understand how using `extern` in the code would get the global variable inside a block where a local variable was defined.

I did study how `extern` works after seeing this but still I couldn't understand: How does 'declaring' a variable(by using `extern int x;`) inside a block help bring up the global variable?

Thank you in advance

Comment: just because you can doesn't mean you should.

Comment: FYI, while this is an interesting example for educational purposes, you should know it's also *very* weird to use `extern` this way.  `extern` declarations are almost always declared near the top of the file, outside any function.  The author of the function normally chooses names of local variables that don't conflict with global names or, less often, that intentionally supersede one.  In 40 years I've never seen a case or need to declare an `extern` the other way around, to hide a local variable.

Comment: @JamesK.Lowden Very interesting, does that mean I won't likely see these kind of declarations in the real world?

Comment: You'll see `extern` plenty at the top of a file. Inside a function, you should report it to the Audubon Society as the sighting of a rare species.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the declaration `extern int x;` refers to `int x;` declared at file scope is an example of how **linkage** works.  An identifier specifying an object or function may have one of the following linkages:

- Identifiers with **external linkage** represent the same object or function in any translation unit (i.e. source file and included headers) in the program.
- Identifiers with **internal linkage** represent the same object or function in one particular translation unit.
- Identifiers with **no linkage** represent a distinct object and only exist in the scope in which they are declared.

In your example, `int x;` at file scope has external linkage because it was not declared with the `static` storage class specifier.

`int x;` declared in the outermost block of the `main` function has no linkage because there is no storage class specifier on it, so this declaration defines a new object which masks `x` declared at file scope.

Now you have `extern int x;` declared in a sub-block inside of `main`.  Because this identifier is declared with `extern`, it is compared with the prior visible declaration, specifically `x` declared in block scope above it.  Since this prior declaration has no linkage, this new identifier has external linkage (it would have internal linkage if the prior declaration had internal linkage).  This is described in more detail in section 6.2.2p4 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier `extern` in a scope in which a prior declaration of that identifier is visible, if the prior declaration specifies internal or external  linkage,  the  linkage  of  the  identifier  at  the  later  declaration  is  the  same  as  the linkage specified at the prior declaration.  **If no prior declaration is visible, or if the prior declaration specifies no linkage, then the identifier has external linkage.**

And because it has external linkage, it refers to the same object as `int x;` declared at file scope.

Comment: @0___________ See my edit.  The new identifier could have either external or internal linkage depending on the linkage of the prior declaration.

Comment: Thanks for the response, It may be obvious for you but why does the code break when I remove the sub-block where `extern int x;` is?

Comment: @Maxjo When you have an identifier with no linkage, it can only be defined / declared once.  So another declaration in the same scope violates that rule.

Answer (score 2):

Every scope may shadow identifiers from the higher-level scope. `extern` declaration show the compiler that somewhere else in the code exists variable `x` having external linkage. This declaration shadows the previous scope variable `x` definition.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x = 50;

int main(){
    int x = 10;
    printf("scope 1: %d\n", x);
    {
      extern int x;
      printf("scope 2: %d\n", x);
      {
          int x = 20;
          printf("scope 3: %d\n", x);
          {
                extern int x;
                printf("scope 4: %d\n", x);
          }
          printf("scope 3 again: %d\n", x);
      }
      printf("scope 2 again: %d\n", x);
    }
    printf("scope 1 again: %d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/YPc6jenEG

```
Program stdout

scope 1: 10
scope 2: 50
scope 3: 20
scope 4: 50
scope 3 again: 20
scope 2 again: 50
scope 1 again: 10
```

More: [How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files)

Comment: In the terminology of the C standard, Identifiers (not objects) are hidden (not shadowed).

Comment: @EricPostpischil amended

Answer (score 1):

Because `int x = 50;` appears outside a function, it declares an `x` that has *external linkage*, which I will discuss below.

Where `int x = 10;` appears, it declares a new `x` that hides the previous `x` of `int x = 50;`. Since this declaration is inside a function, it has no linkage.

Where `extern int x;` appears, it declares a third `x` that hides the previous `x` of `int x = 10;`. Although it is inside a function, the `extern` causes it to have external linkage.

The external linkage of the first `x` and the third `x` causes the compiler (or linker) to resolve them to refer to the same object. So the third `x` refers to the same object as the first `x` even though it is a different instance of the identifier. (Because the second `x` has no linkage, it is not linked to the same object in this way.)